# Reinstall MySQL (mariadb) in Debian Stretch

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I removed mysql completely including configuration files and when I try to reinstall, there is no mysql.socket (I searched in /var/lib/mysql/ and there's nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you will see mysql.sock file when you start the mysql daemon process. This is create the sock file.

But you can also search and see whether it has created somewhere.

```
netstat -ln | grep -o -m 1 -E '\S*mysqld?\.sock'
```

or 
you can check with this command:

```
% mysqladmin variables
```

If you want to create the file, you can do this

```
mkdir /var/mysql
ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

This [thread](https://www.hivelocity.net/kb/what-to-do-if-mysql-sock-file-is-missing/) explains things in more details.